# Rails assertions - best practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm wondering whether it is good practice to sprinkle my code with assertions as to ensure my project logic is working as expected, to catch the occurrence of "things that shouldn't happen".   I have using  *raise "error message" if condition* as tests that parameters etc are set correctly, and similar assumptions are actually true, something lie the following, where I expect that, if *my_method* is called, a particular Foo should have a non-nil sibling, and that a non-nil value is passed to the method:

```
def my_method(value)
  id=Foo.first.id 
  raise "Value is nil!" if value.nil?
  raise "sibling is nil!" if Foo.first.sibling.nil?  
  increment_sibling(id, value)
end

def increment_sibling(foo_id, increment)
  foo=Foo.find(foo_id)
  foo.do_something
  foo.sibling.value += increment

end
```

My question is, is it good practice to throw in assertions like this for "things that shouldn't happen" in production code, where an assertion might bring the program to a halt.  I could conditionally execute the code  only in development, but as the error I am testing for is usally fatal, the production version will simply fail somewhere else, possibly harder to find further down the call chain.  If this is the bad idea, is there a better practice for catching these kind of errors, or is better to simply try to write tests which will catch them and leave out the assertions?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Don't know if it's best for *your* application or not. Failing hard isn't intrinsically bad, but if it's something that may happen in production, and you don't want to continually restart your process(es), it might be better to handle it gracefully.

Comment: Thanks.   The things I'm testing for things that should "never happen" and indicate an error in the program, not "rare state", i.e. program logic errors.   I find that I spend a lot of debugging time hunting down stupid mistakes and its a lot faster if I catcth those mistakes as close to the source as possible.

Comment: Understood, but halting the system is a pretty extreme measure; in general you don't want to take down prod if there's something wrong, if it can be recovered from (e.g., logging an error and stopping processing on a single unit of work).

Comment: Right.  Perhaps best to write those tests as break "problem" if condition && Rails.env = "development" or something like that.

Comment: Are you only writing high-level integration tests? Or are you writing very fine grained automated tests - "unit" tests - that directly test the low-level methods? And are you using Test Driven Development, where you write tests first and only write code in response to new tests failing for the correct reason?

Comment: Most of my investment in tests is in low level unit tests.  I don't start with the tests I admit, I usually figure out the interface and then test the implentations.

Comment: No this isn't a good idea. There are luckily plenty of design patterns that help avoid nil errors, although no production Ruby app doesn't have nil errors.  I recommend reading Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby to get a feel for object oriented design, and to start thinking more about sending messages between objects. For example, where you write `foo.sibling.value += increment`, it 's good to think about how you would send the increment message directly to the object you wish to increment, 'sibling'. Your code is abstract, but in general instances of a class won't talk to each other.

Comment: @PaulByrne A good idea, but it won't solve the OP's original question/problem, which is unrelated.